# Trouble imaging double integration using polar coordinates, with a limitation being a four-leaved rose.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

So I get that the target of integration is $f(x,y)=6+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. I am pretty sure that when considering polar coordinates, my $r$ and $\theta$ bounds comes from the equation $r=5\sin(3\theta)$.

If I draw out the area, my bounds seem to be $0≤r≤5\sin(3\theta)$ and $0≤\theta≤\pi/6$ ?

So, I can write my double integral as

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_0^{5sin(3\theta)} 6+\sqrt{r^2}r  \mathrm{drd\theta}$$

integrating the inside, I get
$$\int_0^{\pi/6} [(30\sin(3\theta))+1/3(5\sin(3\theta))^2|5\sin(3\theta)|  \mathrm{d\theta}$$

then integrating the $\theta$ .... well it gets sort of messy so I'm not going to write it out. I feel like I did this process wrong, firstly I do not know how I should utilize the $z=0$ plane information, and secondly, I feel like the integration on this problem should not have been this tedious. Did I set the wrong integral bounds? Changed to polar coordinates incorrectly?

Comment: You need parentheses in your original. And are you sure about your $\theta$ upper limit? Graph the polar equation,

Comment: @TedShifrin I just rechecked, since its the first octant I should have set the limits from 0 to pi/3 instead of pi/6. After going through the calculations again, I end up with [500/27 + 25/2 pi] which is right! thank you for pointing it out.